Is there a semigroup with a surjective element that isn't injective?
Given an element $a$ of a semigroup $S$, there are two natural functions from $S$ to itself associated to $a$: $l_a(x)=ax$ and $r_a(x) = xa$. I will call $a$ injective (resp. surjective) if both $l_a$ and $r_a$ are injective (resp. surjective).
If $S$ is a monoid, it is trivial to show that $a$ is surjective iff it is bijective. On the other hand, it is easy to show that if $S$ is commutative and $a$ is a surjective element then $S$ is a monoid: let $e$ such that $ae=a$ and let $x\in S$. Since $a$ is surjective, there is $y$ such that $ay=x$ but then $xe = aey = ay = x$ so by commutativity $e$ is an unit. Also $S$ must be infinite since every surjective function from a finite set to itself is injective.
Can there be a (necessarily infinite noncommutative) semigroup $S$ with a surjective element that is not injective?

No, if $S$ is a semigroup with a surjective element $a$, then it is necessarily a monoid. You can just modify your proof in the commutative case slightly: Let $e$ be s.t. $ae = a$. Let $x \in S$. Since $a$ is surjective there is $y \in S$ s.t. $ya = x$. Then $xe = yae = ya = x$, so $e$ is a right unity of $S$. Similarly, there is a left unity $f$ of $S$. But then $f = fe = e$, so $e = f$ is a unity and $S$ is a monoid.

Note that, unlike in the commutative case, requiring surjectivity on one side is not enough to imply bijectivity on that side (or surjectivity on the other side), even for monoids. Indeed, consider the monoid $S$ of all functions $A \to A$ where $A$ is an infinite set. Then $l_a$ being surjective is equivalent to $a$ being surjective, $l_a$ being injective is equivalent to $a$ being injective, $r_a$ being surjective is equivalent to $a$ being injective, and $r_a$ being injective is equivalent to $a$ being surjective. Since surjectivity and injectivity are not equivalent for maps between infinite sets, any surjective but not injective $a: A \to A$ is a left-surjective but not left-injective nor right-surjective element of $S$, and any injective but not surjective $a: A \to A$ is a right-surjective but not right-injective nor left-surjective element of $S$.

That was silly, i should have noticed that my proof easily generalizes to the non-commutative case.

@Carla_ I suppose you might have been thinking of going from just surjectivity on the left to injectivity on the left, which is not true in general.

No, i was aware that surjectivity on the left didn't imply injectivity on the left.
